# assert.that is. not working in coffee-script

Tags: node.js, iced-coffeescript

In my `iced-coffee-script` test I want to check that something is less than expected.
The only library I found for this is [assertthat](https://github.com/goloroden/node-assertthat):

```
assert = require 'node-assertthat'
assert.that (actualSeconds, is.atMost (expectedSeconds))
```

But my code cannot be compiled from `iced-coffee-script` to `js`:

```
error: unexpected ,
    assert.that (actualSeconds, is.atMost (expectedSeconds))
```

I guess it is because of `is`, that is key word in `coffee-script`.
Yes, I know I can use `assert.ok`

```
assert = require 'assert'
assert.ok actualSeconds <= expectedSeconds
```

But in this case it don't show seconds on fail. It only show: `fail: false == true`

So how check that something is less than expected in `iced-coffee-script` test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if I don't like to write pure `js`, I decided to create one module:

```
var assert = require ('node-assertthat')
module.exports = function (actual, expected) {
    assert.that (actual, is.atMost(expected))
}
```